# Modify Woocommerce action for email templates

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce, action

I need to pass data into the footer template for Woocommerce and not exactly sure how to modify the action associated with it. In the body of the email the `$order` variable can be used like such `echo $order->billing_email;` however `$order` in the 'woocmmerce_email_footer' action is not set, as seen below.

How could I get/set the `$order` variable in the email footer action?

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_customer_details', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email );

do_action( 'woocommerce_email_footer', $email );
```

customer detail action is as followed

```
public function order_details( $order, $sent_to_admin = false, $plain_text = false, $email = '' ) {
    if ( $plain_text ) {
        wc_get_template( 'emails/plain/email-order-details.php', array( 'order' => $order, 'sent_to_admin' => $sent_to_admin, 'plain_text' => $plain_text, 'email' => $email ) );
    } else {
        wc_get_template( 'emails/email-order-details.php', array( 'order' => $order, 'sent_to_admin' => $sent_to_admin, 'plain_text' => $plain_text, 'email' => $email ) );
    }
}
```

and the footer

```
public function email_footer() {
    wc_get_template( 'emails/email-footer.php' );
}
```